# Vue.js + vue.router + history mode + Django = Error

Tags: python, django, webpack, vue.js, vue-router

When I'm using `publicPath`: '/static/' in my webpack config, my Vue.js app runs fine on a Django Webserver (both dev and production).

However now I'm trying to use history mode. I have to change the `publicPath` to `"/"`, otherwise the URL always gets a "/static/" in between the domain and actual target.

The Vue.js dev server still runs fine, however both production and development Django server give me these errors in the browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Resource interpreted as
>   Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/6.01a214ce.css".

I've tried several different solutions like:

- publicPath: './'
- assetsPublicPath: '/static/'
- inside base html (gave me an error on compilation)

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

it was actually a framework issue.. im using Quasar..
For some reason you have to change
  base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE,
to
 base: "/",

in router/index.js as the default seems to take the static url when you are using Django..
maybe it helps somebody